# Proving Bertrand's Ballot Theorem using Generator Functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, generating-functions

As a learning exercise, I am trying to understand if it is possible to prove (the famous) **Bertrand's Ballot Theorem** (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand%27s_ballot_theorem) specifically using Generator Functions. I have seen other ways to prove this theorem (e.g. Induction, Reflection) - but I specifically want to see if it is possible to prove this theorem using Generator Functions

Bertrand's Ballot Theorem: In an election where Candidate A has $p$ votes and Candidate B has $q$ votes with $p > q$, the probability that A is ALWAYS ahead in the count is given by $$\frac{(p-q)}{(p+q)}$$

Here is the logic I am using:

- Consider a situation where Candidate A receives $p$ votes and Candidate B receives $q$ votes, where $p > q$. We want to count the number of ways this ballot can be arranged such that A is always ahead.
- Denote the number of ways to arrange these votes such that Candidate  A is always ahead by $B(p, q)$. If $p = q + 1$, there is only one way to arrange the votes (i.e. Candidate A must get the first vote), so $B(p, q) = 1$.
- If $p > q + 1$, consider these two cases:

  - Case 1: The first vote goes to Candidate A. The remaining votes can be arranged in $B(p-1, q)$ ways.
  - Case 2: The first vote goes to Candidate A, the second vote goes to Candidate B. The remaining votes can be arranged in $B(p-1, q-1)$ ways.
- This is where I tried (**not sure if this is correct**) to define the Recurrence Relation: $B(p, q) = B(p-1, q) + B(p-1, q-1)$ for $p > q + 1$
- I read online that  Generating Function are closely related to Power Series (**I don't know why this is**). For $B(p, q)$, I thought we could define a 2 Dimensional Power Series:

  $$B(x, y) = \sum_{p>q} B(p, q) x^p y^q$$
- Using algebraic manipulation, I tried to re-arrange the above relationship to see if I could stumble across any hints that might be useful:

  $$B(x, y) = \sum_{p>q} [B(p-1, q) + B(p-1, q-1)] x^p y^q$$

  $$B(x, y) = x \sum_{p>q} B(p-1, q) x^{p-1} y^q + xy \sum_{p>q} B(p-1, q-1) x^{p-1} y^{q-1}$$

  $$B(x, y) = xB(x, y) + xyB(x, y)$$
- From here, I tried to solve for  $B(x, y)$:

  $$B(x, y) [1-x(1+y)] = 0$$

But I think I am going in circles and not approaching this problem in the wrong way. If $B(x, y) = 0$, this will cancel out all the work I do. And if $[1-x(1+y)] = 0$, I am not sure how I would use this information to continue.

**Can someone please help me understand if Bertrand's Ballot Theorem can be proven using Generator Functions?**

Thanks!

Comment: This is wrong: "If $p=q+1$, there is only one way to arrange the votes (i.e. Candidate A must get the first vote), so $B(p,q)=1$". Indeed Candidate A must get the first vote (that's true irrespective of the values of $p$ and $q$), but then both have $q$ votes left and there are $C_q$ ways to arrange those votes to keep A ahead (where $C_q$ is the $q$-th [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Betrand's ballot theorem can be proven with generating functions. However, the only proof I know starts a bit differently than yours.

Define
$$
b_k(x)=\sum_{n\ge 0} B(n+k,n)x^n
$$
So $b_k$ is the generating function for ballot sequences where $A$ has $k$ more votes than $B$.

**Lemma 1:** For all $k\ge 1$, $$b_k(x)=\big(b_1(x)\big)^k.$$

*Proof*: Extracting the coefficient of $x^n$ from both sides of the generating function equation to be proved, it suffices to shw the following combinatorial equation:
$$
B(n+k,n)=\sum_{n_1+\dots+n_k=n} B(n_1+1,n_1)\cdot B(n_2+1,n_2)\cdots B(n_k+1,n_k)
$$
To do this, we show that any ballot sequence where $A$ has $k$ more votes than $B$ can be uniquely decomposed into $k$ ballot sequences where $A$ leads by $1$ vote.

Given a ballot sequence counted by $B(n+k,n)$, define a sequence of indices $t_0,t_1,\dots,t_k$, where for each $i\in \{0,1,\dots,k\}$, $t_i$ is the index of the last ballot for which the running total for $A$ was exactly $i$ votes ahead of $B$. For example, $t_0=0$, while $t_k=(n+k)+n$. It follows that the sequence of votes between $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$ is a sequence where the running total for $A$ always exceeds that of $B$, and which has one more vote for $A$ than $B$. Therefore, each of the sequence between $t_i$ and $t_{i+1}$ is a ballot path counted by $B(t_{i+1}-t_i+1,t_{i+1}-t_i)$, so the result follows by letting $n_i=t_{i+1}-t_i$.

**Lemma 2**: $$b_1(x)=1+x \,b_1(x)^2$$

*Proof*: Extracting the coefficient of $x^n$ from both sides, we must prove that
$$
n\ge 1\quad \implies \quad B(n+1,n)=\sum_{n_1+n_2=n-1}B(n_1+1,n_1)\cdot B(n_2+1,n_2)
$$
To prove this, let $S$ be a ballot sequence counted by $B(n+1,n)$. Let $t$ be index of the ballot in $S$ where $A$ is one vote ahead of $B$ for the *second* time. We then decompose $S=S_1+S_2$, where $S_1$ is the prefix of $S$ which ends with vote number $t$, while $S_2$ is everything after. Note that $S_1$ is a ballot sequence. It is not quite true that $S_2$ is a ballot sequence, because $S_2$ has an equal number of $A$ and $B$ votes. However, if you delete the final $B$ vote from $S_2$, the result is a ballot sequence. Therefore, letting $n_1$ be the number of $B$ votes in $S_1$ and $n_2$ be the number of $B$ votes in $S_2$ (minus the last vote), we see $n_1+n_2=n-1$, as claimed.
$\tag*{$\square$}$

**Theorem:** For all $n\ge 0$, $$B(n+k,n)=[x^n]b_k(x)=\frac{k}{2n+k}\binom{2n+k}{n}$$

Let $f(x)=b_1(x)-1$. Lemma $2$ can be rewritten to say
$$
\frac{f(x)}{(1+f(x))^2}=x
$$
Therefore, letting $g(y)=y/(1+y^2)$, we see that $f(x)$ and $g(y)$ are functional inverses of each other for which $f(0)=g(0)=0$.

Let $H(x)=(1+x)^k$. We have that
$$
[x^n]b_k(x)=[x^n]\big(b_1(x)\big)^k=[x^n]\big(1+f(x)\big)^k=[x^n] H(f(x))
$$

To solve this, we use the Lagrange inversion formula, which says that whenever $f,g$ and $H$ are analytic functions such that $f(0)=g(0)=0$ and $f\circ g=g\circ f=x$, that
$$
\tag{LIF}
[x^n]H(f(x))=\frac1n[x^{-1}] \big(H'(x)\cdot g(x)^{-n}\big)
$$   Therefore, applying LIF, we have that for any $n\ge 1$,
$$
\begin{align}
B(n+k,n)
&=[x^n] H(f(x))
\\
&= \frac{1}{n} [x^{-1}] H'(x)\cdot g(x)^{-n}
\tag{LIF}
\\
&= \frac 1n [x^{-1}] k\cdot (1+x)^{k-1}\cdot x^{-n}(1+x)^{2n}
\\
&= \frac kn [x^{n-1}] (1+x)^{2n+k-1}
\\
&= \frac kn \binom{2n+k-1}{n-1}
\\
&= \frac k{2n+k} \binom{2n+k}{n}.
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Wow ... what an epic answer.   ... I accepted the answer

Comment: If you have time, do you think you can please show me a much easier way to do prove this? (E.g. without generator functions perhaps)